# How to build tinder type customized ad banner?

Tags: ionic2, admob

I have learnt we cannot customize too much the ad banners, also that the positions of ad banners are predefined and cannot be changed. I am wondering how does tinder show fully customized ad banners in the form of cardview. Also they could be swiped left or right that means their positions are not fixed? Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Tinder but to display such an Ad as you are describing you should start using AdMob Native ads https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native